# how does && work when both the variables are the same?

Tags: groovy, smartthings

I'm learning groovy to work on smartthings and found a relatively common command among the various examples and existing code (see below).

Reading the function of the && operator I would think the "&& cmd.previousMeterValue"  is superfluous.  Or is there some code shortcut I'm missing?

Thanks
John

```
if (cmd.previousMeterValue && cmd.previousMeterValue != cmd.meterValue) {
do something
}
```

Comment: You misread, the precedence is not as you think. This is evaluated as `cmd.previousMeterValue && (cmd.previousMeterValue != cmd.meterValue)` (basically, true if previous value exists, and is different than the current one)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I however I'm not sure why the statement is not simply cmd.prevousvalue != cmd.currentvalue.  However it might be some unique SmartThings requirement.  I'll ask there.  Again thanks, your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing what type `previousMeterValue` has, this answer is somewhat generic.

Groovy follows common [operator precedence](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_operator_precedence), i.e. `!=` is evaluated before `&&`.
To show it explicitly, the full expression is the same as:

```
(cmd.previousMeterValue) && (cmd.previousMeterValue != cmd.meterValue)
```

`cmd.previousMeterValue` is testing the value for the [Groovy-Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth).
Depending on value type, the following might be applicable:

> - Non-null object references are coerced to true.
> - Non-zero numbers are true.

So if the value is `null` or `0`, the expression is `false`.

If the first part of the expression evaluated to `false`, then the second part is [skipped](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_short_circuiting).

> The logical `&&` operator: if the left operand is false, it knows that the result will be false in any case, so it won’t evaluate the right operand. The right operand will be evaluated only if the left operand is true.

If the first part of the expression evaluated to `true`, then `cmd.previousMeterValue != cmd.meterValue` is evaluated, using the [following rule](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_behaviour_of_code_code):

> In Groovy `==` translates to `a.compareTo(b)==0`, if they are `Comparable`, and `a.equals(b)` otherwise.

So if value is a number object, then it is evaluated as:

```
cmd.previousMeterValue.compareTo(cmd.meterValue) != 0
```

This means that `BigDecimal` values are compared by value, ignoring specific scale.